# Как увидеть детализацию Data Driven теста в Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: юнит-тесты, visual-studio-2015

Создал Data driven тест в VS2015. В старых версиях Visual Studio было окно "Test Results", в котором можно было увидеть детальную информацию по каждой строке тестируемого набора данных. Не могу найти это окно в VS2015. Подскажите, как его отобразить.